# Changing SMTP authentication in mutt based on From e-mail address

Tags: smtp, email, mutt

I use [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) as my e-mail reader, and [nbSMTP](http://web.archive.org/web/20071013050201/http://nbsmtp.ferdyx.org/) as my SMTP client. I check e-mail from a half dozen accounts and sort them into miscellaneous folders in my maildir. Some of the folders are account-specific, but some contain e-mails from multiple accounts in one folder

A number of the accounts are through [Gmail](http://gmail.com/), which has the unfortunate security feature of preventing users from sending from addresses that aren't theirs. Thus if I tell nbSTMP to authenticate as `user1@gmail.com` and send an e-mail with a `From: user2@gmail.com` header, Gmail will rewrite the header to `From: user1@gmail.com`.

I've worked around this somewhat by adding folder hooks for the folders that are account-specific; when I switch to one of those folders the hook changes my sendmail command to pass nbSMTP the appropriate command-line arguments:

```
folder-hook =work 'set from="work@example.com"'
folder-hook =work 'set sendmail="/usr/bin/nbsmtp -f work@example.com -U work -P password"'
```

However, this doesn't work for the folders that hold mail from multiple accounts, and it doesn't work if I try to e.g. send e-mail from `work@example.com` when I haven't switched to the `work` folder (since the folder hook hasn't run). **Is there a way to control how nbSMTP authenticates based on the `From` header in the outgoing e-mail?** I don't think nbSMTP has the flexibility to handle it itself, so I'm pretty sure it will have to be some kind of `mutt` configuration like the `folder-hook` method I'm currently using, but I haven't figured out how to do it. If necessary I can probably switch SMTP clients, if there's another that does provide the necessary functionality

Comment: email is a very valid tag here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could switch to esmtp, there it is pretty trivial:

```
identity myself@gmail.com
        hostname smtp.googlemail.com:25
        username "myself@gmail.com"
        password "secret"
        starttls enabled
        default

identity mysecondaccount@gmail.com
        hostname smtp.googlemail.com:25
        username "mysecondaccount@gmail.com"
        password "evenmoresecret"
        starttls enabled
        default
```

Comment: So if I send an e-mail through esmtp that's from `myself@gmail.com`, it will automatically use the credentials from the first identity, and likewise for e-mails from `mysecondaccount@gmail.com`?

Comment: It will use the identity matching the envelope-from, i.e. the address passed to it in the -f parameter. Mutt passes the from address there if you set "set use_envelope_from" in mutrc, see http://wiki.mutt.org/?LightSMTPagents/Esmtp

Comment: Excellent. I'll try that sometime today and accept this if it works

Comment: Ten years later!! Help: Is esmtp still a good choice? Is there a better one? Anyone still using it? How do I call it from Alpine? Or does it run as a once-only daemon like postfix?