# outgoing smtp choose server based on From address

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, alpine-mail

I use an email client called Alpine. Currently I start it in one of several different modes in order to specify the outgoing SMTP server based on what I'm doing, in particular the From address that I wish to use.

What would be much more convenient is if I could simply direct Alpine to use my own SMTP server (on my laptop), which in turn would choose a relay server based on the From address of each message I'm sending.

I am hoping someone is already doing this (it seems like it should be a common need given recent tightening of restrictions on accepting mail) and that it is not complicated.

(As a bonus, I'd also like to be able to start Alpine in a mode which uses a local server that waits until Monday morning to send out messages.)

Here is possibly the same question: [Changing SMTP authentication in mutt based on From e-mail address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/changing-smtp-authentication-in-mutt-based-on-from-e-mail-address), but it is old and so are references on esmtp – I'm not sure esmtp is up to date with modern security protocols, etc.

Comment: At the risk of possibly splitting this question in two, I cannot find out how to call a server like esmtp from Alpine, ie instead of giving it a remote server address, etc, I want to spawn a local process (each email?? Or do I run esmtp once?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer for Alpine email client

Recent versions of Alpine are compiled for Ubuntu with many of the available patches, i.e., enhancements, and these include a feature called "smtp-rules". It's not perfectly well documented, but here is what the `.pinerc` section looks like for me. It handles email addresses from my employer, from my alma mater, and from two Gmail identities:

```
# Unfortunately, using gmail's SMTP servers require setting up 2-factor authorization,
# which then allows you to get an "app password" for each account, which can be used
# by Alpine. Instead of doing this, for now I'm using MIT's, which is changing but
# currently letting through my gmail identities
smtp-rules= _FROM_ == {me@McGill.ca} => _SMTP_{smtp.office365.com:587/tls/user=me@mcgill.ca}
smtp-rules= _FROM_ == {someone@gmail.com} => _SMTP_{outgoing-alum.mit.edu:465/ssl/user=me}
smtp-rules= _FROM_ == {anotheridentity@gmail.com} => _SMTP_{outgoing-alum.mit.edu:465/ssl/user=me}
smtp-rules= _FROM_ == {me@alum.mit.edu} => _SMTP_{outgoing-alum.mit.edu:465/ssl/user=me}
```

### For other clients, or another way using Alpine

I haven't tested esmtp, since the above works nicely, but this seems to be an alternative:

1. Install esmtp
2. Set the smtp-server field to the executable, `/usr/local/bin/esmtp`
3. Put something like the following in your `~/.esmtprc` file:

   ```
   identity joe@mail.com
       hostname mail.server.com:25
       username "joe"
       password "secret"
       starttls enabled
       default
   identity joe@gmail.com
       hostname smtp.gmail.com:587
       username "joe@gmail.com"
       password "secret2"
       starttls required
   ```

Reference for the esmtp part: [Send mail with eSMTP for a simple, single-user system - TechRepublic](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/send-mail-with-esmtp-for-a-simple-single-user-system/).